# How to switch tab bar index after submit data to server successfully?

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller

This code is a save button for sending data to server. After it sent successfully. How to let the view controller go back to tab bar controller and switch it to Index 2? .selectedIndex is not working.

```
if (result == "success") {                                     
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Updated", message: "Update Successfully", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(okButton)
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate! as! AppDelegate

    let initialViewController =self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBarVC")
    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
    appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 2 // this code is not working
}
```

Comment: What is the type of initialViewController?

Comment: tab bar controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
    let initialViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBarVC") as! UITabBarController
    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
    appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    initialViewController.selectedIndex = 2
```

Comment: value of type UIViewController have no member selectedIndex... Sorry I think Its view controller?

Comment: Edited the answer,plz check now